# Inserting scraped data using php curl into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, curl, insert, screen-scraping

I have been working on this script for the last couple of days and cannot seem to find a way to insert the data into MySQL. I am a beginner when it comes to PHP/MYSQL and have only written a couple of simple scripts before. I am able to echo out the scraped data and get no error messages, but when I check phpmyadmin the query isn't working (the results aren't being input to the database).

Here is the code that I have been working on

```
require ("mysqli_connect.php"); 
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('user_agent', 
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.asos.com/Women/Jeans/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=3630&via=lhn');
// find all images

foreach($html->find('#items') as $a)       
    echo $a->innertext .'<br>';

foreach($html->find('span.price') as $p)
    echo $p->innertext .',';    

$q = "INSERT INTO jeans (`image`, `price`) VALUES ('$a', '$p')";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or die ("Update query failed : " . mysql_error());;  //Run the Query.
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, was even struggling with that!

Comment: Try echoing out `$q` and running that in phpmyadmin; that will show if there's an error with your SQL, or if it's with your database connection.

Comment: You might wanna insert $a->innertext and $p->innertext , if they contain valid values.

Comment: You have both mysqli_query and mysql_error. Considering your require is for mysqli_connect, I think the mysql_error() function at the end should be mysqli_error(). That may help you get more information.

Comment: Thanks Kingcoyote, I hadn't spotted that. I changed it to mysqli, which is showing me the error message: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /domainname.com on line 32

Comment: I tried your solution Eswar and it gets rid of the mysqli_error and runs the query but it inputs a solitary blank record into the MySQL database. What I need it to do is to insert 20 records at once, all on separate rows. Is this possible?

Comment: What I'm having a problem with guys is inserting $a->inner text . into the database. $a->inner text consists of 20 different results and I want to add all of them to the database using an insert query at the same time. Is this possible?

Comment: It's an ASP powered site so when you move between pages it will be sending several form parameters such as VIEWSTATE using the  POST method. Just performing a simple URL + variables GET request will be refused.  To scrape the site you will need to mimick a web browsers behaviour using cURL or similiar.

Answer (score 2):

In your sample code, $a and $p are objects, try this instead:

```
$a = '';
foreach($html->find('#items') as $item) {
    $a.= $item->innertext .'<br>';
}

$p = '';
foreach($html->find('span.price') as $price) {
    $p.= $price->innertext.',';    
}
```

Next, remove the @ from @mysqli_query, try not to use that, ever, try to catch/handle errors properly instead.

Next, please take a few minutes to research paramaterized queries and PDO, don't accept unknown input (from 3rd parties no less) and inject them right in to your sql:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO jeans (`image`, `price`) VALUES ('$a', '$p')";
```

ie: Don't do that ^

Finally, you probably want to validate the response from the get.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Somedev, thank you for taking the timeout to review my question and offer a solution. Where you've defined the $a and $p variables, should I leave it blank in between the quotation marks? Also I looked into parameterized queries and PDO as you suggested but just can't get my head round it as I am a massive novice. How would I implement it here? It's exactly what I wish to do: multiple insert queries. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are suppressing the error by putting an @ before `mysqli_query`

Try changing this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO jeans ('image', 'price') VALUES ('$a', '$p')";
mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or die ("Update query failed : " . mysql_error());;  //Run the Query.
```

Comment: Hi edwardmp. Thanks for responding so quickly. I have now removed the @ sign and implemented somedev's above code, but now it's just echoing out Update Query Failed :

Answer (score 0):

I' think I know what is wrong.

If you just use

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.asos.com/Women/Jeans/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=3630");
```

(or just asos.com, doesn't matter), you will notice that you'll always get back:

> Sorry, we can't find that page or something has gone wrong...
>
> go back or try here:
>
> women men home help desk

Because none of the elements you specified are on this page, you're code will return nothing.

**My guess is that asos.com prevents scraping from their site.**

Comment: You're probably not faking your user agent. If you look at the above code I set my user agent to Mozilla as they allow them to scrape their site. So I can retrieve the info but I just can't seem to insert it into my database :(

Comment: check my other post. Travis Pessetto has adjusted it to replace the backticks with single quotes.

Comment: It is neater to define the user agent in the code than the .ini. Use something like this; `$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => 'UserAgent/1.0');
file_get_html('http://www.google.com/', 0, $context);`

Comment: Ok, I'll make that adjustment so that it's clearer. I'm still no closer to adding the desired content to the database though :s. I've scraped the page successfully and can echo out the data using either $a . or $p . but I can't seem to input this data into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use mysql_real_escape_string function to avoid troubles saving your contents. Example below.

```
$query2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO jeans(image, price)  
                 VALUES ('%s','%s')",mysql_real_escape_string($a),
                                     mysql_real_escape_string($p))
mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$query2);
```